# If/Else in powershell to determine StrongAuthenticationStatus - powershell

Tags: powershell

So I am trying to come up with a reliable method to determine if a user has o365 multi factor authentication configured on their account prior to a script running so They do not get re-enabled.

using:

```
$MFAUsers = Get-Msoluser -userprincipalname test.webjea@xxx.com  | select "StrongAuthenticationRequirements"
```

outputs if they are enabled

```
StrongAuthenticationRequirements
--------------------------------
{Microsoft.Online.Administration.StrongAuthenticationRequirement}
```

and the following if they are disabled

```
StrongAuthenticationRequirements
--------------------------------
{}
```

Ideally if the user is disabled then the script will run against their account enabling it.  If they are enabled then the script will skip them.
For testing I have this drawn up

```
if ($MFAUsers -eq "{Microsoft.Online.Administration.StrongAuthenticationRequirement}") {
"NO MFA"
} 
Elseif ($MFAUsers -eq "{Microsoft.Online.Administration.StrongAuthenticationRequirement}"){
"MFA"
}
```

When running this against the test account that has been enabled I still get the "no MFA" response

Anyone have any idea?  I'm sure it is something stupid but I really cant put my finger on it?  Is it seeing the "StrongAuthenticationRequirments" header?

Answer (score 1):

The test you are doing is the same for the `if` as for the `elseif`.
When `{Microsoft.Online.Administration.StrongAuthenticationRequirement}` is returned, it means that MFA is enabled for that user. When the function returns `{}` the user has no StrongAuthenticationRequirement set.

I cannot test this myself, but running the below code should show you which users have "MFA" enabled and which users do not.

```
# test for all users would be Get-MsolUser -All
Get-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName 'test.webjea@xxx.com' | 
    Select-Object DisplayName, UserPrincipalName,
                  @{ Name = "MFA"
                     Expression = { 
                        if($_.StrongAuthenticationRequirements.Count -ne 0) { 
                            $_.StrongAuthenticationRequirements[0].State
                        } 
                        else { 'Disabled' }
                     } }
```